# Play20 embed an external js file

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

From my play20 application i need to generate a HTML file which includes all the external .css/.js/etc.

To generate the HTML file i use 
    views.html.MyView(Parameter).toString()

But i need to replace the:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/bootstrap.css")">
```

with

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
  @icludeTextFrom(routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/bootstrap.css"))
  This function should read the bootstrap.css file and embed it's content here.
</script>
```

Is there some functionality in Play 2.0 to embed an other file or do i have to copy the content of the files by hand?

Thanks
Fabian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's functionality:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://somedomain.tld/somescript.js">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
    Bootstrap code
</script>
```

In other words: using `src='@routes...'` isn't obligatory thing, it's just a helper, you can also replace with static files. You can also add whatever you want to your view, because it's **your** view.

Comment: My question is probably not so good but what i need is a way to embed the content of somescript.js in my view. (In the end i need one html file where all scripts etc. are embedded.

Comment: @Fabian: Why do you want to render views with `toString()` is that some special reason?

Comment: Yeah i need to generate a HTML file of some specific data which can be looked at without internet access. (Sounds strange but that is what we need ;)

Comment: The fastest thing you can do is just put the CSS and JS in the head section of MyView, you can also use some Java methods for reading file contents to String and pass as a next param: http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString(java.io.File, java.nio.charset.Charset)

Answer (score 1):

I have now added a small function which will add the content of an external file.

```
@embed(what:String) = @{
  import java.io.File
  scala.io.Source.fromFile(new File(".").getCanonicalPath() + "/public/" + what).mkString("")
}
```

which get used like:

```
<style type="text/css">
  @embed("stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css")
 </style>
```